# Remove elements from the array of objects using object attribute (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Have an array of objects:

```
{ sid:11, scode:"code", sname:"Sam" },
{ sid:12, scode:"code", sname:"Sam" },
{ sid:13, scode:"code", sname:"Sam" },
{ sid:14, scode:"code", sname:"Sam" },
{ sid:13, scode:"code", sname:"Sam" },
{ sid:139, scode:"code", sname:"Jake"}
{ sid:134, scode:"code", sname:"Jake"}
```

Needs to remove from this array only objects with sname:"Sam" and sid:13.
And in the result get next:

```
{ sid:11, scode:"code", sname:"Sam" },
{ sid:12, scode:"code", sname:"Sam" },
{ sid:14, scode:"code", sname:"Sam" },
{ sid:139, scode:"code", sname:"Jake"}
{ sid:134, scode:"code", sname:"Jake"}
```

Javascript (or jQuery) examples are very appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/).

Comment: You have to show some of your efforts to find solution by yourself. This is not "give me a code" type of website. Btw, welcome aboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easy to accomplish with `Array#filter`

**Example**

```
var array = [{ sid:11, scode:"code", sname:"Sam" },
{ sid:12, scode:"code", sname:"Sam" },
{ sid:13, scode:"code", sname:"Sam" },
{ sid:14, scode:"code", sname:"Sam" },
{ sid:13, scode:"code", sname:"Sam" },
{ sid:139, scode:"code", sname:"Jake"},
{ sid:134, scode:"code", sname:"Jake"}]

var newArray = array.filter(function(element){
    if (element.sid === 13 && element.sname === "Sam")
        return false
    
    return true
})

console.log(newArray)
```

**Another Example**

Here is another example, using different functions in the array prototype to make a function similar to Underscores reject method.

```
var reject = function(array, params) {
    return array.filter(function(element) {
        return !Object.keys(params).map(function(key){
            return params[key] === element[key]
        }).reduce(function(memo, bool){
            return memo & bool
        })
    })
}

console.log(reject(array, {sid: 13, sname: "Sam"}))
```

---

#### Useful Links:

- `Array.prototype.filter` [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

---

#### Less Useful, but Helpful Links:

- jQuery filter function: [jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)
- underscore.js reject function: [Underscore Documentation](http://underscorejs.org/#reject)

Comment: don't forget `sname:"Sam"`

Comment: You are not using jQuery's filter method, what you are using is the `Array.prototype.filter` function.

Comment: I know I am not, figured I would be a nice guy and share that with him as well. But thanks for pointing that out.